# How does the SE Podcast record high quality sound with more than one user?

Tags: discussion, podcast, audio

I've been listening to the podcast for quite a long time now, and the sound quality is great - even when interviewing many participants from different countries.

How is this done, technically? Obviously, the sound quality is higher than the average Skype call.

Does each participant record its own voice simultaneously, and the different channels are synced later? this seems to be quite difficult.

Any ideas?

**Update:** I would appreciate a practical solution I could suggest to some Podcast I know, which records calls via phone on a mediocre quality.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So the way we accomplish this is by running independent skype calls to each of the guests, recording those calls on their own channels, editing the audio and then mixing all of the channels down into a single mp3 file. Ill be doing a blog post soon that covers all the details of our setup.

**UPDATE:** The post is up - you can check it out @ https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-se-podcast-setup/

Comment: Great! Looking forward to read your post.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know much about the technicalities of the podcast, but they do seem to just record incoming Skype audio; if you watch it live you can listen to them call someone over Skype and play with the individual audio streams. They definitely don't all record individual audio; [Alex Miller](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/159928/alex-miller) has something running on his computer that records everything so he can produce the final audio

Comment: Shame. I guess their internet connection is far better than mine. Any idea how to do this on low-bandwidth connection?